# R Makevars: how to evaluate command for preprocessor flags?

Tags: r, cran

When I am creating an R package with compiled code, the `Makevars` file which sets additional compilation flags is able to execute arbitrary commands within the build process in order to pass compile-time variable flags to the linker - example `Makevars`:

```
MY_FLAGS = `${R_HOME}/bin${R_ARCH_BIN}/Rscript -e "cat('-lmylib')"`
PKG_LIBS = $(MY_FLAGS)
```

However, if I try the same trick for the pre-processor flags instead, it will not work:

```
MY_FLAGS = `${R_HOME}/bin${R_ARCH_BIN}/Rscript -e "cat(1)"`
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -DMyFlag=$(MY_FLAGS)
```

Will instead issue the full command without evaluating it, unless I change it to use `shell`:

```
MY_FLAGS = ${shell ${R_HOME}/bin${R_ARCH_BIN}/Rscript -e "cat(1)"}
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -DMyFlag=$(MY_FLAGS)
```

... however, according to the R extensions manual, packages are not supposed to use `shell` like that due to non-portability.

How can I pass preprocessor flags that involve running R itself to evaluate some command?

I realize it's possible to instead create a `Makevars.in` and put the code that needs execution in the `configure.ac`, but is there some other way it could be achieved **without** a configure script?